# Changes in the mouse button

Tags: mouse

Until now every time I pressed the right mouse button it showed me a long menu that includes copying and pasting etc, but suddenly it shows me a 'new collection' - how do I go back to the previous mode?

Comment: can you show me what exactly it looks like? However you can change anything back to default just by going to **Edit -> Preferences -> (down-left icon) Load factory preferences**

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as you wrote and the problem was solved.